# Eclipse: Run command every time when opening/switching to workspace

Tags: eclipse

Is it possible to run a command every time I open a specific workspace in eclipse?

I would like to use it to run: `compass watch [path]` to automatically generate css files from scss in projects using sass.

**EDIT**

To expand on the answer given. To run a command in the Workspace Dir in Ubuntu:

```
String workDir = ResourcesPlugin.getWorkspace().getRoot().getLocation().toString();

ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("gnome-terminal","-e","bash -c 'compass watch;exec /bin/bash -i'");
pb.directory( new File( workDir ) );
pb.start();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can do that. You have to write plugin for this. You have to use  `org.eclipse.ui.startup` extension for this and install this plugin on you host eclipse.See this [help](http://help.eclipse.org/luna/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fextension-points%2Forg_eclipse_ui_startup.html).

In the start up code check the current workspace and write code.

```java
 if(ResourcesPlugin.getWorkspace().getRoot().getLocation().toString() ==     "/home/chandrayya/xyz") {
  //write your code here
 }
```

I don’t know which plug-in contributed the action/command `compass watch [path]`. Find out the plug-in and check whether it gives any extension points to call this command and use it.